# The system can't find file specified in python

Tags: python

Below errors came While I was installing `pip install django_auth_ldap`

> system can't find file specified:C:\Program Files(*86)\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v8.1\bin

Before that I have installed Built tools Microsoft Visual C++ also

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: I will guess this has to do with `Program Files(*86)`. Pretty sure that folder is called `Program Files(x86)` on windows. Unless this was a typo on your part?

Comment: @smac89 .yes Folder name is Program Files(x86)